# How spring framework manage cyclic dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am relatively new to using spring framework. I have read below advantages of using spring :

*...Containers also provide support for instantiation of managed objects, cyclical dependencies, life cycles management, and dependency resolution between managed objects etc....*

How does Spring achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [dependency resolution process](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-dependency-resolution) section in the Spring Framework reference (search for "Circular dependencies" note at the sidebar).

Basically, you need to use setter-based injection instead of constructor-based one. Otherwise, you'll get an exception when the container creates your beans (if you're not using lazy initialization).